# Unresolved symbols in QClasses when using querydsl with Spring Boot, Gradle and Idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, querydsl

I am trying to build up an API with spring boot using querydsl. I have managed to to get the QClasses to generate using the Gradle plugin but I am unable to use these classes as the QClasses all of their imports as unresolved. I am attaching the relevant files and screenshots as to how things look.

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "eclipse"
    id "idea"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.1.RELEASE"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.9"
}

querydsl {
    querydslDefault = true
    jpa = true
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('src/querydsl/')
        generatedSourceDirs += file('src/querydsl/')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.1.3"
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

This produces the QClasses like this

[image: Project]

As you can see, one tiny issue is that I can't open the tree to the querydsl module anymore. I am able to open the tree if I remove `sourceDirs += file('src/querydsl/')`. I don't know if this is intended or not.

My repository class is as such

```
public interface BotRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Bot, UUID>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Bot>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QBot> {
}
```

But I get this in IntelliJ
[image]

This tells me that there is something wrong with the project module setup even though I am adding the sources in the Gradle. After I click on the `Add dependency on module`, I am allowed to import the class. But then again, I get an error
[image]

I am pretty sure this error is occurring because the QClass is not unable to resolve the imports. This is how it looks
[image]

And this is where I am stuck. I am unable to proceed with the API. Any help will be appreciated.

**P.S.**: I know there are answers which show how to setup the gradle and I set mine up using those and decided to use the querydsl gradle plugin. So, I am not expecting to remove the plugin and go the other way (read: querydsl-apt:jpa)

Answer (score 0):

I also got some problems running Gradle + Spring Boot + QueryDSL on Eclipse. But, I noticed some important points:

1) On my notebook, it ran correctly as Java Application or Spring Boot App from eclipse

2) On my desktop, it did **not** ran as Java Application

3) On my desktop, it ran correctly as Spring Boot App

4) On my desktop, it ran correctly using the command line: gradle bootRun

I am still intrigued by the first observation...

Anyway, please find the build.gradle I used. I hope it helps...

```
plugins {
         id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.8.RELEASE'
         id 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl' version '1.0.9'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
     querydslVersion = '4.1.4'
}

wrapper {
         gradleVersion = '4.3.1'
}

repositories {
              mavenCentral()
              maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
}

dependencies {
              compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
              compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
              compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
              compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
              compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

              compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:$querydslVersion")

              testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

querydsl {
          springDataMongo = true
          querydslSourcesDir = 'src/generated-sources/java'
          library = "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:$querydslVersion"
         }
```